# Can't resize my exFAT partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have an exFAT partition that I can't resize, with GParted nor Ubuntu Disks.

Here is what I see with Disks

[image]

And GParted shows this warning when I display the information of this device:

> Unable to read the contents of this file system!
>
> Because of this some operations may be unavailable.

I tried running Gparted with `sudo -i gparted`, this does not change anything.

This device is not read-only, I can delete files if I want.

I tried running `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb3` and here is the result:

```
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

(PS: I'm open to suggestion if there is a better file system to share files between Linux/Windows/MacOS)

Comment: exFAT is probably the best alternative to share files between all 3 main operating systems, Linux/Windows/MacOS. It is best to use Microsoft tools to modify Microsoft file systems (and exFAT is a Microsoft file system). So do it in Windows.

Comment: `ntfsfix` is only for NTFS partitions.  You need to install the proper exfat tools - `exfat-tools` and `exfat-fuse`.  However, these are more or less for *reading* exFAT partitions, not modifying them.  You should probably be booting to Windows to resize the exFAT partition, or do it by hand on the command line.  Also, *never* use `ntfsfix` for non-NTFS partitions

Comment: FYI also, even with exFAT tools installed, GParted only has support for moving and copying partitions, not creating, growing, shrinking, checking, labeling, or doing UUID functions with them.  You can see this in View > File System Support in GParted.  Ubuntu/GNOME Disks inherits the same levels of functionality, and these're usually indicators system-wide of support, not just with these tools.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your comments, I'll try later on a Windows machine!

Comment: Couldnt we use a Windows virtual machine from the Linux system to resize exfat partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it's hard (impossible?) to resize an exFAT partition in Ubuntu.

I managed to resize my partition with the use of [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/), as advised in these  SuperUser answers: https://superuser.com/questions/511819/resize-exfat-hard-drive & https://superuser.com/questions/393132/shrink-exfat-partition